# How to use XPath or xgrep to find information in Wikipedia?

Tags: xml, xpath, wikipedia

I'd like to scrape some (not much) info from Wikipedia. 
Say I have a list of Universities and their Wikipedia page. Can I use an xpath expression to find the website (domain) of that University?

So for instance, if I get the page

```
curl http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vienna_University_of_Technology
```

this xpath expression should find the domain:

```
http://www.tuwien.ac.at
```

Ideally, this should work with the Linux `xgrep` command line tool, or equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

With `h` prefix bound to `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` namespace URI:

```
/h:html/h:body/h:div[@id='content']
               /h:div[@id='bodyContent']
                /h:table[@class='infobox vcard']
                 /h:tr[h:th='Website']
                  /h:td/h:a/@href
```

Also, it looks like Wiki page are well formed XML (despite the fact that are served like text/html). So, if you have an XML document with the pages URLs like:

```
<root>
   <url>http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vienna_University_of_Technology</url>
</root>
```

You could use:

```
document(/root/url)/h:html/h:body/h:div[@id='content']
                                  /h:div[@id='bodyContent']
                                   /h:table[@class='infobox vcard']
                                    /h:tr[h:th='Website']
                                     /h:td/h:a/@href
```

Comment: Hi @Alejandro, That looks great, but the xgrep tool I have does not accept this. Is there a command line (Unix/Linux) tool that you can recommend?

Answer (score 0):

> it looks like Wiki page are well formed XML (despite the fact that are served like text/html)

Apparently, that's no longer true. I had to use `xmllint`'s `--html` option to convert the document to well-formed xml.

```bash
curl -L https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vienna_University_of_Technology \
| xmllint --html --xpath "//table[@class='infobox vcard']//tr[th='Website']//a/@href" -
```

Result:

```
href="https://www.tuwien.at/en/"
```

**Note:** I added the `-L` option to the `curl` invocation to follow the redirect to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TU_Wien.

As you see, it returned a node-set consisting of one attribute node. The [string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/string) function can be used to get the string value of the first node in a node set. For an attribute node, it returns the attribute's value as a string:

```bash
curl -L https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vienna_University_of_Technology \
| xmllint --html --xpath "string(//table[@class='infobox vcard']//tr[th='Website']//a/@href)" -
```

Result:

```
https://www.tuwien.at/en/
```

✔️

**Update:** I found that it *is* possible way to retrieve the article as well-formed XML. The [action=parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=parse) API can do it. Here's the end result:

```
curl -L 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=Vienna_University_of_Technology&format=xml&redirects' \
| xmllint --xpath "string(/api/parse/text)" - \
| xmllint --xpath "string(//table[@class='infobox vcard']//tr[th='Website']//a/@href)" -
```

Notice that the `--html` option is no longer needed.