# XPath on Wikipedia Summary

Tags: xpath

I'm currently trying to extract the blurb, or summary from any given Wikipedia page, using XPath. Now, there are many places online where this has already been done: http://jimblackler.net/blog/?p=13, [How to use XPath or xgrep to find information in Wikipedia?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509191/how-to-use-xpath-or-xgrep-to-find-information-in-wikipedia).

But, when I try to use similar XPath expressions, on a variety of pages, the returned results are strange. For the sake of this question, let's assume I'm trying to retrieve the very first paragraph in the printable Wikipedia page on Boston: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Boston&printable=yes.

When I try to use this expression `/html/body/div[@id='content']/div[@id='bodyContent']//p`, only the last four words of the paragraph, "in the United States.", are returned.

Actually, the expression used above could be simplified to `//div/p`, but the results are the same.

Strangely, the links I linked to previously seem to use similar methods and return great results; originally, I imagined this was due to Wikipedia changing the formatting of their pages in recent years, but honestly, I can't seem to find what's wrong with both the expressions.

Does anyone have any idea about this?

Comment: What are you using to run the expressions?

Comment: Well, I'm developing for the Mac in Objective-C, and using the XPathQuery library. But here, I think the problem is more likely linked to my expression and the Wikipedia content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I try to use this expression
>   `/html/body/div[@id='content']/div[@id='bodyContent']//p`, only the
>   last four words of the paragraph, "in the United States.", are
>   returned.

**There are a few problems here**:

1. **The XML document is in a default namespace**. Writing XPath expressions to select nodes in a document that is in a default namespace is the most FAQ about XPath -- search for "XPath and default namespace". In short, any unprefixed name will most probably cause nothing to be selected. One must register the default namespace and associate a specific prefix with this namespace. Then any element name in the XPath expression must be written with this prefix. So, the expression above will become:
   :

> ```
> /x:html/x:body/x:div[@id='content']/x:div[@id='bodyContent']//x:p
> ```

where the `"x:"` prefix is associated to the `"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` namespace.

.2. **Even the above expression doesn't select (only) the wanted node**. In order to select only the first `x:p` from the above, the XPath expression must be specified as (note the brackets):

> ```
> (/x:html/x:body/x:div[@id='content']/x:div[@id='bodyContent']//x:p)[1]
> ```

.3. **As you want the text of the paragraph**, an easy way to do this is to use the standard XPath function `string()`:

> ```
> string((/x:html/x:body/x:div[@id='content']/x:div[@id='bodyContent']//x:p)[1])
> ```

**When this XPath expression is evaluated, I get the text of the paragraph** -- for example in the XPath Visualizer I wrote some years ago:

[image]